# Sample code for homescreen widget which has a button and is updated via service

Tags: android, android-widget

I have read a number of tutorials on this topic but not able to make it working. Can anyone please help me with the following

a) A home screen widget which has a button, Imageview and a TextView
b) The textview updates periodically via a service
c) On Click of the button the Image Changes.

Can anyone please help with a sample code or point to codes which do this functionality

Answer (score 0):

check out this book, it explains very clear how to make a widget "silent mode toggle"

http://iit.qau.edu.pk/books/Android.Application.Development.for.For.Dummies.pdf

Answer (score 0):

a) In your xml, the following will be the code.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/go" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@string/welcome" />
```

Of course, you need to arrange them according to your fancy.

b) Updating the text view is no big deal. Getting the text from the source is what is important. If it is from a web page, you could refer to usage of JSON. If it is from a database, then try SQLite. It all depends on your necessity. 
Lets assume that you get your text. Your code for updation will be:

```
TextView t =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
t.setText(your_string);
```

To do it periodically you can use a parallel threading concept such as a runnable.

c) Set up an on Click Listener for this purpose.

```
Button b1;
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
b1.setOnClickListener(button_func);
```

This comes in your onCreate method.

```
View.OnClickListener button_func = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
               image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
               iv.setImageResource(R.id.new_image);

                                            }
                  };
```

Hope that you find this useful

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks but this is for a normal widget, A home screen widget is different findViewbyId does not work there

Comment: The corresponding change in syntax is available at [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)